# Stuck on a select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a query that i've been struggling with.

I have 2 tables:

Prices & Visitors

Prices:

In this table the first column represents the age groups (0-4, 4-12, 12-80) with their corresponding prices

**AgeGroup**

0
4
12
80

**Price**

0
5
20
15

Visitors:

**Name**

Cindy
Bob

**BirthDate**

2001-01-28
1958-03-01

I'd like to have one select statement show me the names of the visitors and the prices that they'll have to pay.

So i'll probably need something akin to this to get their age:

year(curdate()) - year(visitors.BirthDate)

and then i'm guessing that i'll need something like this as well:

where max(Prices.AgeGroup) <= year(curdate()) - year(visitors.BirthDate)

Unfortunately that's where i'm stuck, i've already been at it for quite some time now but i still haven't been able to create the desired result yet.

Anyway if anyone could give me a helping hand, i'd very much appreciate it. :)

Comment: Two possibilities: specify in your age group column the minimum age. Calculate the actual age. The age group is the group with the highest minimum age that's less or equal the actual age.

Comment: Added a query in the answer, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT 
visitors.name, visitors.birthdate, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '00-%m-%d'))   
AS age, (select price from prices where age_group < age order by age_group desc limit 1) as price
FROM 
visitors
```

Here's [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4996/2) for you.

Comment: I wouldn't use your expression to get the age. There are such things as "leap days".

Comment: Well, what would you suggest. I wouldn't mind a few days around, but do think this expression would work: DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), birthdate)), "%Y")

Comment: Fixed the query now to handle leap years. [link]https://ma.tt/2003/12/calculate-age-in-mysql/

Comment: You're too fast. I've presented the same algorithm today here at SO.

Comment: No, I meant the one above. We were out of sync :-) I've deleted my comment that could be misunderstood.